# How does yarn find a module installed as a dev-dependency

Tags: yarnpkg, package.json, vuepress

script object in the package.json files is the modern replacement for Gulp or a similar build tool. Assume that Vuepress is installed with `yarn add -D vuepress` (meaning that the vuepress is installed locally in the node_modules folder.

Further, assume that the package.json file contains the following script object:

```
"scripts": {
    "docs:dev": "vuepress dev docs",
    "docs:build": "vuepress build docs"
  }
```

How does the command `yarn docs:dev` executed in the terminal resolve the `vuepress` object? More often than not a similar invocation results with the error `vuepress not recognized ...`

P.S. Since I do not have `vuepress` in the path environment variable the only place where it can be resolved is in the root level node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guessed correctly - both npm and yarn (invoked from the terminal) have the ability to inspect all environment variables, as well as search the folder node_modules. In my concrete example, running the command

```
npm run env | grep scripts
```

results with

```
npm_config_ignore_scripts=
npm_config_scripts_prepend_node_path=warn-only
npm_package_scripts_docs_build=vuepress build docs
npm_package_scripts_docs_dev=vuepress dev docs
npm_package_scripts_env=env
```

There is a lot more information in the article `https://techsparx.com/nodejs/tools/npm-build-scripts.html`